# What is the validity of the electoral train voucher in Italy?

Tags: trains, italy, vouchers

Communal elections are coming this month in Italy, and as an Italian citizen residing abroad, I have received a voucher for a reduced-fare return train ticket (a few years ago it used to be a free ticket actually) to the city to vote

I reside in France, and was looking to take that offer.

Trenitalia, since recently serves Paris and Lyon, so I was wondering if that voucher would be valid and entitle me to a reduced fare return from France to Italy or, if not, what exactly is the validity range of those vouchers.

Comment: Because this is in Italian, I'm not going to add an answer: https://www.trenitalia.com/it/informazioni/elettori.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the link posted by mkennedy in a comment](https://www.trenitalia.com/it/informazioni/elettori.html) (formatting not reproduced):

> Agevolazioni per i viaggi degli elettori
>
> I residenti in Italia possono ottenere, esclusivamente per viaggi di andata e ritorno in 2^ classe per tutti i treni del servizio nazionale e per il livello Standard dei Frecciarossa, le seguenti riduzioni:
>
> - 70% del prezzo Base per i treni media-lunga percorrenza nazionale (Frecciarossa, Frecciargento, Frecciabianca, Intercity e IntercityNotte) e servizio cuccette;
> - riduzione 60% sui biglietti per treni Regionali.
>
> In ogni caso, sono fatti salvi i minimi tariffari previsti per ciascuna categoria di treno.
>
> Per i residenti all'estero è prevista la tariffa Italian Elector (viaggi internazionali da/per l'Italia a bordo dei treni Eurocity Italia-Svizzera).
>
> Il viaggio di andata può essere effettuato dal decimo giorno antecedente il giorno di votazione (questo compreso) e quello di ritorno fino alle ore 24 del decimo giorno successivo al giorno di votazione (quest’ultimo escluso).
>
> In ogni caso il viaggio di andata deve essere completato entro l’orario di chiusura delle operazioni di votazione e quello di ritorno non può avere inizio se non dopo l’apertura del seggio elettorale.

Machine translation:

> Facilitation for voters' travel
>
> Residents in Italy can obtain, exclusively for round trips in 2 ^ class for all trains of the national service and for the Standard level of the Frecciarossa, the following reductions:
>
> - 70% of the basic price for medium-long distance national trains (Frecciarossa, Frecciargento, Frecciabianca, Intercity and IntercityNotte) and couchette service;
> - 60% reduction on tickets for Regional trains.
>
> In any case, the minimum tariffs for each category of train are reserved.
>
> For residents abroad there is a Italian Elector fare (international travel to/from Italy on board Eurocity Italy-Switzerland trains).
>
> The outward journey can be made from the tenth day before the day of voting (including this one) and the return day until 24 hours on the tenth day following the day of voting (the latter excluded).
>
> In any case, the outward journey must be completed by the closing time of the voting operations and the return journey cannot begin until after the opening of the polling station.

This page also contains [a link to a PDF document](https://www.trenitalia.com/content/dam/tcom/allegati/trenitalia/condizioni-generali-di-trasporto/parte-i---norme-comuni/Allegato_6-Agevolazioni_elettori.pdf) that similarly mentions only Switzerland in connection with voters living abroad.  My Italian is somewhat limited, so I cannot determine quickly whether this is beneficial to a resident of France whose route includes the train from Geneva or Basel to Milan.  I suspect that it is not, because it applies to "Elettori provenienti dalla Svizzera," which I suppose means that these provisions are limited to those who reside in Switzerland.

There is some additional information that is certainly relevant:

> Elettori provenienti dall'estero che abbiano raggiunto l'Italia con altri mezzi
>
> Agli elettori provenienti dall'estero giunti in una stazione di confine (sono considerate stazioni di confine
> anche tutte le località sede di aeroporto internazionale) con mezzi propri o con quelli di altri vettori,
> vengono emessi biglietti di andata e ritorno per elettori, con applicazione delle riduzioni previste in
> servizio nazionale per viaggi di andata e ritorno da e per la stazione di confine fino alla stazione che serve
> il Comune sede elettorale, purché siano in grado di comprovare la residenza all’estero ed esibiscano la
> documentazione elettorale prevista.

Machine translation, slightly edited:

> Voters from abroad who have reached Italy by other means
>
> Voters from abroad who arrived at a border station (they are considered border stations
> also all locations where the international airport is located) by its own means or by those of other carriers,
> return tickets are issued for voters, with the application of the reductions provided for in national service for round trips to and from the border station to the station serving
> the municipality of the polling station, provided that they are able to prove their residence abroad and produce the required election documentation.